# Is my 32 bit & 64 bit installers in the wrong directories?

Tags: windows, windows-installer, 32bit-64bit

I'm having trouble installing a 64 bit program on my windows PC.

I'm running windows 7 64 bit.

Looking in regedit after a bit of googling I noticed the files seem to be in the opposite directories to what I think they should be.

[image: 64 bit - 32 bit mixed up]

Comment: Why do you care about the internal locator implementation of the 32-bit and 64-bit versions of msiexec.exe? This is almost certainly nothing to do with your issue. If your setup doesn't work then post a question and describe the scenario, error messages etc. It seems pointless to worry about msixec.exe locations!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope, those look correct to me. They are indeed confusing at first, and can be difficult to talk about.

- System32 is the native system directory, and happens to be misleadingly named on a 64-bit system.
- SysWow64 indicates the system directory for the Windows (32)-on-Windows 64.

Note of course that only a 64-bit application, or one that has disabled redirection, can use a path containing "System32" to reach the 64-bit files it contains.